# C++17 alternative implementation for std::transform_reduce

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, backwards-compatibility

Im working on a project which was developed using c++20 standard ,but I need to build it on  an old embedded linux device which the highest available standard is c++17(gcc 8.3.0). analyzing the code base, I realized the only c++20 feature requirement that forbids the code to be compiled is the lake of the `std::transform_reduce` that gets the following error:

```
error: ‘transform_reduce’ is not a member of ‘std’
```

the referred part of code is:

```
auto addresses_string = std::transform_reduce(
    localAddresses.begin(), localAddresses.end(), std::string(""),
    [](const std::string& a, const std::string& b) {
      return a + " | " + b;
    },
    [](InetAddress addr) { return addr.str(); });
```

but as I check the std documentations it seems the c++17 has most of the std::transform_reduce signatures implemented. this project is a CMake based project and it contains the following variables set to use the c++17 standard

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```

I was wondering if im doing something wrong or is there an possible alternative implementation available for the missing function in c++17 or how can I implement the same logic without changing the programs high level behavior.

Comment: Can't you just build a newer gcc for your device?

Comment: `error: ‘transform_reduce’ is not a member of ‘std’` This means that you're only using a *partial* C++17 implementation. `transform_reduce` is C++17 functionality, so it ought to be there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution that doesn't sacrifice expressiveness involves writing your `transform_reduce` as a simple `std::accumulate`. To do this you need a utility to generate a `map_reduce` operator:

```cpp
template <class M, class R>
auto map_reduce(M&& map, R&& reduce) {
    return [m = std::forward<M>(map), 
            r = std::forward<R>(reduce)](auto& acc, auto&& val) mutable {
        return r(acc, m(std::forward<decltype(val)>(val)));
    };
}
```

your call can then be is written in C++17 as:

```cpp
std::accumulate(
    localAddresses.begin(), localAddresses.end(), std::string(""),
    map_reduce(
        [](InetAddress addr) { return addr.str(); },     // transformer    
        [](const std::string& a, const std::string& b) { // accumulator
            return a + " | " + b;
        });
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49176ea94182302b) (using numbers converted to strings instead of addresses).

Reduction (`std::accumulate` / `std::reduce`) can pretty much do anything if you figure out how to express your accumulator. To get a sense of how deep the rabbit hole goes, check [this presentation](https://sinusoid.es/talks/transducers-cppcon15/#/).

---

A more mundane solution would be to "borrow" the implementation of `transform_reduce` (say from [here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/78d6a7767ed57b50122a161b91f59f19c9bd0d19/include/numeric#L231C1-L252C2)) and make it available in a header only if

```cpp
#if __cplusplus < 202002L // Using standard older than C++20
  // implementation goes here
#endif
```

Of course in a cross platform project, you'd have to account for the combination of language standard and compiler since some library features are implemented out of standard order.

Comment: If it is available, you can use `reduce` instead of `accumulate`. You may want to invert parameters in `map_reduce`. This way changing the `transform_reduce` call involves just slapping `map_reduce(` in front of the last two parameters.